# How can I set a sub subfigures parameters?

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, subfloats, includegraphics

I am looking for way to set the figure according to the following configuration. I've tried embeded subfigures but it didn't work!!!!
[image: figures]

Answer (score 1):

Images may be positioned just like letters, I use a `tabular` here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-10x16}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-10x16}  &
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-10x16}
\\
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-10x16}  &
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-10x16}
\end{tabular}

\caption{5 images}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. but how about the subcaptions, how can I get (a) (b) ,,,, (e) displayed in the buttom of each subfigure ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Carlisle didn't get around it, this uses the same tabular (more or less) with `\subfloat`.

I like to add `\floatsep` between rows with captions, but `\\[\floatsep]` doesn't work since the baseline for `\subfloat` is at the bottom of the image.  So I added an empty row and compensated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-10x16}}
\end{tabular}% sapcing ame as one big tabular
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-10x16}} &
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-10x16}}
\\
\\[\dimexpr \floatsep-\arraystretch\normalbaselineskip]% tricky
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-10x16}}  &
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-10x16}}
\end{tabular}

\caption{5 images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, It worked exactly like i hoped but now I do have an other propblem with refrencing the subfigures, the label of the hole figure work but the labels of subfigures get "?" in the text .

Comment: You should put `\label` inside the optional argument of `\subfloat` (possibly the other argument as well).